# Is there a way to plot a specific value when I clicked two points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick

I'm working on a project that when you click two points it will plot the x and y values that I set. I'm new to matplotlib so I don't know if it's possible to do.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 10])

    def onclick(event):
        print('button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
        (event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))
        if event.x == 215 and event.x == 420:
           plt.plot([2,5],[3,3])

    plt.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata, '-ro')
    fig.canvas.draw()

    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
    plt.show()
```

I expected that every time I clicked two points, the values that I set to plot will appear.

Comment: Could you please specify how the code doesn't work? The intended behaviour is unclear. And I suspect `plt.plot(event.xdata ...)` has wrong indentation: on that line `event` doesn't even exist, that line should be inside the `onclick` function definition.